# How do I set up a group blog (i.e. multiple authors) in SharePoint Online?

Tags: blog, communication-site

I'm familiar with individual blogs in SharePoint Online. But I'd like to create a group blog. It would have multiple authors contributing to one blog. I'd prefer an OOTB solution and I'm open to solutions that would provide blog-like functionality (likes, comments) even if they don't use the SharePoint blog engine. Responsiveness would be a big plus.